# Can't update my graphics driver because my computer is blocking Geforce from my graphics card

Tags: windows-10, drivers, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an Asus ROG GL552VW laptop, with a Nvidia GTX 960M graphics card

So I've been having this issue for a while, but I've never seen it get this bad until now. Sometimes when I'm running graphics intensive software, like steam games or Inventor, my computer will freeze and an error message will pop up saying "Application 'program'.exe has been blocked from graphics hardware". Usually I could get around this by just rebooting the laptop and running it at lower settings.

But over time it's been happening with even less intensive software. And it's gotten so bad that when I tried to update the graphics driver today through Geforce Experience, it froze and blocked it before I could even pick between a custom or express install.

I tried looking online for help but, ironically enough, the only answer I could find was to update my graphics driver. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

What can actually help in these instances is giving the Microsoft approved drivers from Windows Update a shot.

- Uninstall Geforce Experience if you don't urgently need any of its features.
- Go into Device Manager and for the GPU Display Adapter right click and select "Uninstall"
- Reboot PC
- Go back into Device Manager and right click on your GPU entry and select "Update Driver". If nothing is showing up you can also select at the top Action > Scan for Hardware Changes

The drivers probably won't be the most up to date but they might be more stable. Also check Asus' support site for any new chipset and BIOS drivers for your laptop since those can affect this too.